# How can fix error (Mixed Content) when i uploed my project to herkou

Tags: heroku

**Hello I have problem when I deploy my website to Heroku it's work in local but when Heroku it not working **

**this error display**

> Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure stylesheet ''. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WETdJ.png)
**I know it need content for HTTPS not HTTP but how can  I make content by HTTPS **

Comment: ....which parts of that error message are unclear? What have you tried to spot and solve the error?

Comment: please check for my answer  updated  image error

Comment: And what have you tried to solve that error?

Comment: yes I'm tried solving but l cant

Comment: And **what** have you tried? It should not be too hard to load all resources protocol-agnostic

Comment: try to make https in my url in Laravel Because   i'm using Laravel  but doesn't work and aloes try to change App_url in .env  aloes  doesn't work ..but when try to change url in path Heroku to HTTP it's work

Comment: Well, if your application does anything to switch between HTTP and HTTPS, maybe you want to share more details on this topic?