# I have problem when deploy my laravel on herkou (Mixed Content)

Tags: laravel, heroku, https

Hello …  l am finish Building website using Laravel and jQuery and bootstrap it's working good in local but when I upload to Heroku  the file jQuery and bootstrap not working … it's work in local using http but in Heroku its need https its not working but when write http substitute of https it's working good like local and display Not Secure .. now any body know how can i allow website using https in Heroku or How can selection this problem

[image]

Comment: See: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/getting-mixed-content-error-when-viewing-website-over-https?page=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can fix error (Mixed Content) when i uploed my project to herkou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297995/how-can-fix-error-mixed-content-when-i-uploed-my-project-to-herkou)

Comment: You asked a very similar question just seven hours ago ☝️. Be _patient_. We're mostly volunteers, and it can take some time to get a response.

Comment: I 'am  very sorry to nuisance  u Because I've been busy fixing the problem for more than a day, but I couldn't

Answer (score 1):

You should closely read all of [Heroku's guide to getting started with Laravel](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel).

The section titled "Trusting the Load Balancer" will resolve your issues.

Because of this:

> This means that requests received by a dyno will have the last router’s IP address in the REMOTE_ADDR environment variable, and the internal request will always be made using the HTTP protocol, even if the original request was made over HTTPS.

Laravel sees HTTP requests coming in to the application, so it serves HTTP URLs for your various routes and asset URLs. As far as it knows, you're browsing via HTTP. The fix is to trust Heroku's "forwarded for" headers in your app's `App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies` middleware:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    protected $proxies = '*';
    protected $headers = Request:: HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue myself awhile back, there are a few options and some are more heavy handed than others. If you want to gauruntee that everything is always https no exceptions first update your `APP_URL` to 'https://example.com' then in the boot method of your AppServiceProvider add `Url::forceScheme('https');`

The less heavy handed option is to find all of the places you use the `asset()` helper and change it to `secure_asset` instead. The asset helper should use your APP_URL to know the request is https but in my experience I couldn't rely on that so use secure_asset to make sure

Comment: thankyou a lot I  using app_url  not working I have tried before  but now trying  your answer  secure_asset it is work good